# Defining additional make targets using gnu autotools

Tags: makefile, autotools, automake

I am beginning to learn autotools in order to first understand and later extend an existing project's build system. Currently the project builds a program as it's output. The build system is quite complex consisting of several subdirectories and `Makefile.am`'s with files generated in a maintainer-mode and so on. I would like to optionally be able to create a library using much of the same source code, reusing much of the the existing build system.

What I am imagining is a new make target so that after running configure, I can then run either `make` to make the program, or, say, `make library` to build the library. What is the correct way to do this or something with a similar effect?

I do not want to build both the library and program when I run plain `make` (just the program as before), and I do not want to build the program when I run `make library` (I only want the library).

If someone could provide a simple example, e.g. a program made up of `main.c`, `foo.c` and `bar.c` and a library made up of `foo.c` and `bar.c` that would be really helpful too.

EDIT

To clarify, I originally thought that the program and lib could be built entirely separately. The library contains only a subset of the code of the main program, and I believed the two were separate entities. However, things are more complicated. The program itself is built and used to output some code which is then compiled into the program in a second step (I think). I have effectively got what I want by doing the following steps.

First add a conditional to configure.ac

```
dnl Adds LIBRARY conditional for --enable-foolib mode to
dnl build foo as a library
AC_ARG_ENABLE(foolib,
AS_HELP_STRING([--enable-foolib],
               [enable qucslib build, default: no]),
[case "${enableval}" in
             yes) foolib=true ;;
             no)  foolib=false ;;
             *)   AC_MSG_ERROR([bad value ${enableval} for --enable-foolib]) ;;
esac],
[foolib=false])

AM_CONDITIONAL(FOOLIB, test x"$foolib" = x"true")
```

Then in the appropriate Makefile.am I did something similar to the following:

```
if FOOLIB
noinst_LIBRARIES = libbar.a libfoo.a
else
noinst_LIBRARIES = libbar.a
endif

bin_PROGRAMS = barprog

barprog_SOURCES = main.cpp src1.cpp src2.cpp etc.cpp

barprog_LDADD = libbar.a              \
    subdir1/libsubdir1.a                  \
    subdir2/libsubdir2.a          \
    etcdir/libetc.a 

... other stuff

if FOOLIB
libfoo_a_LIBADD = libbar.a            \
    subdir1/libsubdir1.a                  \
    subdir2/libsubdir2.a          \
    etcdir/libetc.a 

libfoo_a_SOURCES = src1.cpp src2.cpp etc.cpp
endif
```

Then when I want to make the library I do

```
configure --enable-foolib
make
```

This works for now, but seems kludgy. I wasn't sure though how to implement the provided answer in the build system.

Comment: It can do that.  What have you tried?

Comment: Break them up.  Put the library in one project, and the program in another.

Answer (score 0):

If the program depends on the library, then it will not be possible to build the program without building the library.  You already have the ability to build individual libraries: `configure && make libfoo.a` should work just fine (or `make libfoo.la`).  If you wish a target named `library`, you can simply add the following to any Makefile.am:

```
library:
        libfoo.a
```

(Or you may need `libfoo.la`.  Basically, if the library is specified in `Makefile.am` under the `LIBRARIES` primary, then you would use `libfoo.a`, but if specified under an `LTLIBRARIES` primary, you would use `libfoo.la`.)  This will only create a `library` target in each directory that contains a Makefile.am.  If you have a complex recursive build (you should really simplify it, but that's another question), you can put something like the following in your top-level `Makefile.am` to build the libraries throughout the tree:

```
library:
        cd subdir && $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) library
```

This assumes you have added a `library` target to subdir/Makefile.am as described above.

To be pedantic, you might want to use `$(am__cd)` instead of `cd`, but it's not strictly necessary.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not exactly sure how to implement what you are saying, and it also turns out the situation is more complex than I thought. I have edited my question to reflect this.